# create event log channel under 2 node levels

Tags: c++, windows, etw

im trying to create logging mechanism using Microsoft event log ETW
the problem that im facing is how i can create my channel path to be located under 2 nodes , this is my man file similar to this code

```
<instrumentationManifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events eventman.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:trace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">

<instrumentation>
    <events>
        <provider name="Foo-Bar" guid="{some guid}" symbol="name" resourceFileName="some dll" messageFileName="some dll">
            <channels>
                <channel name="Foo-Bar/Admin" chi="AdminCHID" symbol="CHANNEL_BAR_ADMIN" type="Admin" enabled="true" message="Some message" />
            </channels>
        </provider>
    </events>
</instrumentation>
```

this code create the channel in under one node level [image]
and when i change the provider name to this

```
<instrumentationManifest xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events eventman.xsd" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:trace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">

<instrumentation>
    <events>
        <provider name="Foo-Bar-Test" guid="{some guid}" symbol="name" resourceFileName="some dll" messageFileName="some dll">
            <channels>
                <channel name="Foo-Bar-Test/Admin" chi="AdminCHID" symbol="CHANNEL_BAR_ADMIN" type="Admin" enabled="true" message="Some message" />
            </channels>
        </provider>
    </events>
</instrumentation>
```

the channel will created under 3 node leve [image]

what i need is how i can creat my admin channel to appear under 2 node levels

Comment: remove the - before **-TestAdmin**. maybe this helps. I only use .et, here ETW is simpler to setup

Comment: sorry for the confusion , i edit the second xml
each dash (-) indicate for a node separator but it not work when i use Foo-Bar